# Undefined reference to 'function' that has been defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've started learning C++ and trying to figure out how header files work.
I have
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fibonacci.h"
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){
   int n;
   cin >> n;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       cout << fibonacci(i) << ", ";
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

fibonacci.h

```
#pragma once
int fibonacci(int n);
```

fibonacci.cpp

```
#include "fibonacci.h"

int fibonacci(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

But while building I get `undefined reference to 'fibonacci(int)'` error.

I'm using VSCode and g++ compiler.

Comment: Did you modify your `tasks.json` to build both files? The default configuration only builds the active file. The instructions how to build using more than 1 source file are here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: That's indeed not a C++ problem but rather a problem with your VSCode configuration. You should be able to compile it fine manually, e.g. via `g++ main.cpp fibonacci.cpp -o main`